# Passenger or Nginx not working with Custom Domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I made `Ruby on Rails` app on DigitalCloud with `Passenger` and `Nginx`. Everything works fine until I added my custom domain. I simply filled `DNS page` on DigitalCloud and from domain hosting provider directed domain to server IP. Then I changed server name to new URL at `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`.

Here the error:

```
There was an error while trying to write to Gemfile.lock. It is likely that 
you need to allow write permissions for the file at path: 
/var/www/formas_app/Gemfile.lock (Bundler::InstallError)
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:253:in `rescue in lock'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:238:in `lock'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/environment.rb:34:in `lock'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `setup'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler.rb:121:in `setup'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:399:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:277:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:404:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-5.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:276:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-5.0.7/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:99:in `preload_app'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-5.0.7/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:153:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-5.0.7/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-5.0.7/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Here is my `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    passenger_friendly_error_pages on;
    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-5.0.7;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/wrappers/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  mydomain.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        root /var/www/my_app/public;
    }
}
```

Can't figure out what is the problem. 
Thanks anyways!

**Edited my question:**
When I run `bundle install` Passenger error page went off, but now I have standard rails error page showing up. I guess its step forward, but I still need help :D

Comment: I think its an Folder and File permission issue so please give appropriate permission and try.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run `bundle install` in your `/var/www/formas_app` directory. Looks like the user used for running the app with passenger does not have permissions to do so.

I suggest looking into [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) for a more streamlined deploy that will take care of this for you every time you deploy.

Comment: After running `bundle install` Passenger error page went off, but now I have standard rails error page. What do you think?

Comment: What is the error you're seeing? did you try searching the message in google? if you can't see the error message you should try digging through your rails app log. If there's nothing fishy there try the nginx logs.